# Android send ArrayList the object

Tags: android, android-activity, arraylist, send

I'm clumsy.

solution on my problem

origin activity

```
    public void marcas(View view) {
    ArrayList<Localizacion> object = new ArrayList<Localizacion>(localizaciones);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CompraVenta.class);
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable("ARRAYLIST", (Serializable) object);
    intent.putExtra("BUNDLE", args);
    startActivityForResult(intent, RESPUESTA_ACTIVIDAD);
}
```

destiny activity

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_compra_venta);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle args = intent.getBundleExtra("BUNDLE");
    ArrayList<Localizacion> object = (ArrayList<Localizacion>) args.getSerializable("ARRAYLIST");
    loc = object;
    enlaceInterfaz();
}
```

in the class Localizacion i'm implement Parceable.
my mistake was to want to use the arrays like I use them in the java class and that's not how it works.

thanks for all

Comment: Please post the code, not images...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post your code as code, not as images. You should indent the code snippet by 4 spaces to get them in `code markdown`. Use the "edit" link below your post to edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `class` as `Parceable`, and then you will be able to pass the list of objects of that class to another **Activity**.

```
class Localizacion implements Parceable {

}
```

Now to send data to another `Activity`.

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("array",object);
```

In receiving side

```
loc = getIntent().getParcelableArrayExtra("array");
```